# C++ polymorphism using tagged unions

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unions

I was playing around with polymorphism in C++, and I found out about std::variant. However it doesn't seem very performant nor coding friendly, and in most cases you have to use virtual base class anyways.

So I "reinvented" the tagged union, that allows you to store multiple classes and allows you to call their member functions almost directly depending on the stored type.

Consider that I have the following classes containing methods with the same signature:

```
struct A {
    void print() { printf("A"); }
    char id() { return 'A'; }
};

struct B {
    void print() { printf("B"); }
    char id() { return 'B'; }
};

struct C {
    void print() { printf("C"); }
    char id() { return 'C'; }
};

struct D {
    void print() { printf("D"); }
    char id() { return 'D'; }
};
```

Now I have a tagged_union class, that contains the union of all the classes along with stored type id, and implements their methods using internal switch (not the real use case, just an example, I really use it in a raytracer for storing different primitive meshes):

```
 struct tagged_union{
    tagged_union(){}
    tagged_union(A val): a(val), type(0) {}
    tagged_union(B val): b(val), type(1) {}
    tagged_union(C val): c(val), type(2) {}
    tagged_union(D val): d(val), type(3) {}
    void print() {
        switch(type){
            case 0: a.print(); break;
            case 1: b.print(); break;
            case 2: c.print(); break;
            case 3: d.print(); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    char id() {
        switch(type){
            case 0: return a.id(); break;
            case 1: return b.id(); break;
            case 2: return c.id(); break;
            case 3: return d.id(); break;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
    private:
    union{
        A a;
        B b;
        C c;
        D d;
    };
    int type;
};
```

Now my question is: is it possible to automate this process of defining the union (eg. variadic templates + recursively defining the members), and selecting the correct stored type in member functions at runtime, without having to write out switch for each member function ?

I apologize for any grammar errors, and incorrect terminology, as I'm not a native speaker.

Edit: It was clarified to me, that you don't have to use virtual in order to call polymorphics functions from variant.However I still stand by the original question out of sheer curiosity.

Comment: Why not using a `std::variant` in 1st place?

Comment: Well, you could store a global array of class method pointers, then for your function calls simply select the entry indexed by `type` and invoke the associated method, instead of using `switch`. Oh, hang on a moment... That sounds an awful lot like how _virtual tables_ work, doesn't it. That's indeed how polymorphism in C++ is typically implemented. So, is there any specific reason you're not using conventional polymorphism? Where are your benchmarks demonstrating that your union-based approach is superior?

Comment: Unless it's an initial and absolute requirement, please try to create good, maintainable, scaleable and working code first of all. If it's performance isn't "Good Enough™" (and good enough almost always *is* good enough) then measure, benchmark and profile to find the top one or two bottlenecks in your code, to try and optimize those (with plenty of documentation and comments).

Comment: With my above comment in mind, why don't you just **try* plain normal and standard C++ polymorphism? What is the actual problem that `std::variant` or your tagged union should solve, that inheritance and polymorphism can't?

Comment: It's not at all apparent that your code will provide any better performance than `std::variant`, and at least to me, `variant` looks a lot easier to use as well.

Comment: @paddy
 Mainly performance reasons, this way you can avoid shortcomings of conventional polymorphism. You can store this structure in a contiguous memory (no array of pointers) and avoid overhead of virtual calls (mostly), since compiler can possibly inline the member functions.

Comment: "doesn't seem very performant nor coding friendly, and in most cases you have to use virtual base class anyways" its not clear what exactly you mean by that or how your solution addresses those points

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number 
I originally thought that you have to use virtual functions in order to call polymorphic functions in variants. I was wrong.

Comment: I think when you say "virtual base class" you acutally mean "public base class (with virtual methods)"

Comment: That generic class you seek is essentially `std::variant`. Implementimg `variant` is tricky and needs high level of skills and experience. It is possible to implement it more efficiently than the one in `std`, but is it worth the effort and time?! You'll have to deal with varidic templates and none-trivial recursions; development cycle will be long and nerve-wracking. The other (older) option is to use type punning to define the `variant`; it cuts the amount of required code, but has become obsolete due to memory safety concerns. All in all, `std::variant` is the choice to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create template method to do the dispatch once (or twice for `const` version):

```
template <typename F>
decltype(auto) call(F f) const
{
    switch (type){
        case 0: return f(a);
        case 1: return f(b);
        case 2: return f(c);
        case 3: return f(d);
    }
    throw std::runtime_error ("Unreachable code");
}

void print() const {
    call([](const auto& u){ u.print(); });
}
char id() const {
    return call([](const auto& u){ return u.id(); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/488cfj16P)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! You are the best !
Looking at it, is that what std::visit does ?

Comment: `std::visit` does indeed the equivalent.

Comment: As much as this is useful, it doesn't perfom very well in my usecase. About 20% slower than manual switch :/. I  would expect optimizer to do much better.

Comment: @PanJa if this is 20% slower than the manual switch then something else is wrong. Do you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: No, I'm squeezing every last possible drop of performance with -O0 optimizations... :D I will definitely try to look into it some further, rn it's not really a priority.

Comment: A badly performing implementation with -O0 can be the fastest using -O3. It really makes no sens optimizing code with compiler optimisations disabled.

Answer (score 4):

So your four classes stored in an variant would be `std::variant<A, B, C, D>`.

Code to create (for example) a vector of those objects, and invoke each one's `print` member function could look like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    using T = std::variant<A, B, C, D>;

    std::vector<T> objects = { A(), B(), C(), D() };

    for (auto const& obj : objects)
        std::visit([](auto o) { o.print(); }, obj);
}
```

Using each one's `id()` would be similar, except (of course) replacing `o.print()` with `o.id()`.

Not sure of circumstances under which you'd use virtual inheritance in conjunction with `std::variant`. I've used `variant` fair amount for a few years now, and I'm pretty sure none of the types involved ever used virtual inheritance (nor even normal inheritance with virtual functions).

Comment: Then I've looked at bad examples. Sorry about that.
I've looked at the generated assembly and it's mostly the same for both cases...
https://godbolt.org/z/zeW7rxnvj
I'm using the manual approach, because 4 bytes to store just a tag seems wastefull, so I pack extra flags for the meshes in there.
But really thanks for clarifying the usage of variants.
Still no-one answered my question. Is there a way to automate it or not in C++ ? Out of sheer curiosity.

Comment: @PanJa: I thought what I showed pretty clearly showed how you can automate it with `std::variant`. Of course, what's done with variant can also be done without it. As far as four bytes vs. one byte goes: even if you only use one byte, your compiler is almost always going to pad the total size to a multiple of something like 4 or 8 bytes anyway, so (at least for this example) it's not going to make any real difference.

Comment: But it does make a difference when packing the structures. This way I can put the tag wherever I like for optimal memory layout, and use the extra bits for other stuff. Using variant locks me into having to store 4 byte tag, and another 4 bytes for flags. In my specific usecase thats 96 vs 112 bytes with padding :)

Comment: There's nothing that says `variant` has to use a 4-byte type tag (though it's probably fairly common). Ultimately, if your needs are specialized enough, it's inevitable that a class written specifically for those needs can meet them better than a generic one. If I had to write one myself, I'd still work at keeping the same interface as `std::variant`, just with internal optimizations to store a smaller tag where you see fit.

Comment: @PanJa The compiler (or standard library) doesn't just add padding for fun, it's needed to make structures aligned. On some hardware unaligned access could come with performance penalties, or not be allowed at all. So packing the structures and data might save memory (which isn't a big deal unless you're working on a severe memory-constrained target system, which you have told us anything about really, it's kind of crucial information if that's your goal), but can come with performance penalties. Memory or performance is a very common trade-off, and it's often not possible to get both.

Comment: @PanJa the way to automate the switchs is to use a `std::variant` as member instead of the union. Then you can replace the switch with usage of `std::visit` as shown in this answer. Thats one major reason why `std::variant` exists. To replace such long switches that you need with a tagged union

Comment: @PanJa here https://godbolt.org/z/Exdv8Tvna `sizeof(A) == 1` and `sizeof(std::variant<A,B,C,D> == 2`. You should measure before trying to roll your own. Dont do premature optimization

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
That seems to be the special case... Try adding int data element to the classes, size jumps to 8 instead of 2.
https://godbolt.org/z/M6E57j37b

Comment: @PanJa and your tagged_union takes the same 8 https://godbolt.org/z/a96ccKTcP. I am nots saying that it is impossible to do better, I just dont see the obvious opportunity to do better that you try to adress with your `tagged_union`

Comment: But in general usage, tag will be almost always 4 bytes. 
Anyways, I tried implementing variant into my codebase (lambda using reference, so mesh data doesn't get copied). It runs about 60% slower with a lot of small sphere meshes (16 vs 42 fps). For fewer large meshes the performance is almost the same.

To sum it up. I'm sticking with my approach, so I don't have to rely on clearly flawed behavior of variants in critical codepath.  Thanks for your time discussing with me.

Comment: @PanJa consider that the standard library has to provide facilities that are "ok" for all usecases. Finding that specialized approach works better for one use case is not a surprise and calling `std::variant` "flawed" for this reason is a bit exaggerated. That said, 60% sounds a bit too much, though its not possible to say something about it without seeing the code. However, if it works for you then go for it, it just doesnt imply that `std::variant` would be broken